# Why are all activities showing Unknown for the User/Actor .NET Server API w/React-JS client components

Tags: getstream-io

I am working on a proof of concept with GetStream.io using the .NET server side API to add activities and the react-js client components to render feeds.  For some reason every activity is coming into my feeds with Unknown in bold at the top.  I assume this is supposed to be the username or something?  I read a post about passing in a reference to the user instead of the string userId but the .NET API constructor signature creating a new Activity only takes in a string userId parameter.  I have verified that I am passing in a valid userId.  Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you try with { actor : getStreamClient().currentUser } and see if that helps?

Comment: @StephenHodgetts that looks like the Node-JS client API, I am working with the .NET server-side API at the time I am creating and posting the activities.  There is no concept of currentUser b/c the server side apis just use API key and API secret and don't authenticate as a particular user.  From what I can see in the .NET API  Actor is defined as a string on the model...

Comment: I did try fetching the User object, serializing it and then passing that JSON string as the value for Actor on AddActivity instead of just passing the userId but I am still getting Unknown

Answer (score 0):

Stream stores the unique reference and replaces it at read time. In some complex cases, you need to be able to generate a reference to an existing object and embed that inside of an activity.

```
Then, can you try this way:
// Since we know their IDs we can create a reference without reading from APIs 
var userRef = Users.Ref(userId); 
// And then add an activity with these references 
var activity = new Activity(userRef, activityAction, message)
```